# Why does my image height not work when using percentage?

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have a DIV that has an img element nested inside of it.

```
<div> <img /> </div>
```

I gave the DIV a width of 50% and height of 20%. I gave the image a width and height of 100%.

The img takes the 50% width of the parent DIV but doesn't take 20% height...

Why does it not respect the height?

For some reason, the image gets a height of 50% even tho I gave it a height of 20%...

Comment: Try changing image display to block.

Comment: I did, still same problem...

Comment: Share your code, so that contributor can make a solve